# What’s the best way to remove this drywall texture?

Tags: drywall, texture

[image]

Just wondering what is the best method to remove the trowel pattern on my ceiling, want to take out the “pizza” pattern. Thank you.

Comment: Knock off the high bits then plaster over... or put a plasterboard over...

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. @SolarMike's probably right, but a close-up picture, and knowing what the underlying material is (is it drywall?) would help us help you.

Comment: Do you know the vintage? An asbestos test would be an exceptionally good idea. If you tested positive, then either remediation (expensive and complicated) or encapsulation (cover it with new rock) would be appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! I have not taken possession of the house yet, just completed the contract and anticipating renos. 

House was built in 74, house inspection came out negative for asbestos on the surface -- like insulation/HVAC tape/tiles, but I dont think they tested drywall for it.   Encapsulation seems like te best idea, thanks!